# Bound for expectation of random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, random-matrices

Let random matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{C^{\mathrm{m} \times \mathrm{n}}}$ and random vector $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{C^{\mathrm{m} \times 1}}$ are unknown distributed, but their covariance and correlation are known, $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{X}}$, $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{y}}$, and $\mathbf{C}_{\mathbf{Xy}}$. The question is whether there is any bound for the following expression, (like Cauchy-Schwarz or Jensen's)

$?\le \mathbb{E}[(\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{y}] \le ?$

Also, I have to mention $\le$ here means an element-wise inequality since the corresponding expectation is an $\mathrm{n} \times 1$ vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, of course not.

Indeed, consider a simplest case when $m=n=1$, and $X:=\mathbf X$ and $y:=\mathbf y$ are iid standard normal random variables. Then
$$E(\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{X})^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}} \mathbf{y}=E\frac yX$$
does not even exist (because here $\frac yX$ has [the standard Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Properties)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes what you say is true, but I should add something. Here all random variables in both matrix $\mathbf{X}$ or $\mathbf{y}$ are from passing gaussian variable through sign function. As you know the resulting variable doesn't have known distribution, but at least the amplitude of each element (of  matrix $\mathbf{X}$ or $\mathbf{y}$ ) can not be zero, so that fraction would be bounded.

Comment: @AminRadbord : I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "Here"? by "are from passing gaussian variable through sign function"? by " the resulting variable"? by "the amplitude"? by "fraction"?

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis: I mean, assume in my question we have this assumption, 
each element in  $\mathbf X$ or $\mathbf y$ is a random variable which is the output of the sign function where the input is a Gaussian random variable. For example, if m=1 and n=1, then X = sgn(z) and y = sgn(t), in which both z and t are gaussian random variables. so as a result, both X and y can not be zero so $\mathbb{E}[\frac{y}{X}]$ is bounded.

Comment: @AminRadbord : This is a completely different question, which should be posted separately. There is nothing like this $\text{sgn}$ condition in your post -- which only had "unknown distributed".

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis: Maybe, but as you know still the distribution for that variable as an output of the sign function is unknown.  This fact that where the variables are from is the only difference in the question. By the way, I added an update in the post, no need to post it separately.

Comment: @AminRadbord : One should not change the question so as to invalidate a valid answer. Such actions on your part may make people reluctant to spend their time to answer your questions -- nobody wants to waste their time. So, please restore the original question and finalize this matter appropriately.

Comment: @ Iosif Pinelis: Okay I did as you asked. so please look my new post named 'Bound for an expectation of random matrix with quantized random variable'. thanks a lot